# Calling addSubview after removeFromSuperview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on a simple UI, but am running into trouble with `addSubview` calls made after a `removeFromSuperview`.

In my **viewController** I have an IBOutlet `UITableView`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Depending on the state of the data, I remove the tableview from my viewControllers view.

```
[self.tableView removeFromSuperview];
```

So far so good, the view is removed. When using the debugger, I can still see that my viewController has a valid handle to the tableview. The problem starts on the next line when I call addSubview.

```
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
[self.tableView setDataSource:studyResult];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

It seems to do nothing and I can't see any change in the UI. I have tried to set the frame on the *tableView* and still no results.

Have any of you seen this behavior?

Joe

Comment: Is `self.view` valid?  (In particular, is `self.view == self.tableView`?)

Comment: Both objects seem valid and not equal to one another. '<UIView: 0xa4cefb0;...'    '<UITableView: 0xb910800;...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Joe can you give me more code for see what are you going? what I get, is that you have your control and a *tableview* view inside that you want to shot just when you have your *array* with the data? if is like that why you don't set Hide the tableview when you haven't the data? every time that you refresh the data for the table you have also to use the method `reloadData` for refresh the table

Comment: Joe I tell you that because , when you remove your table, it's release from ARC, so when you try to readd it to the view nothing happen because the table doesn't exist

Comment: Things work great when I use alpha values in order to show and hide the table. I would prefer to remove and add the view, isn't that "cleaner"? I didn't realize that the table was being released even though I have a valid pointer to the tableView. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> Depending on the state of the data, I remove the tableview from my viewControllers view.

Consider segueing to another view controller with a table view instead of swapping out table views in a single view controller. Or, if the new data is a subset of the old data, then leave the table view in place and filter its data.